# Should I hash a password inside or outside of a class?

Tags: php, security, hash, authentication, passwords

I have a class called User which stores user information. One field that is store while i am creating the account (it isn't stored in the class otherwise) is the hashed password.

The password is passed via a from from when the user creates an account in a POST to another page for processing with the MYSQL data insertion etc.

My question is, should I pass the raw `$_POST['password']` field into the class and hash it inside the class, or should I hash the password on the outside and pass the hash to the class for storage?

I cannot see any real plus or minus to swing me either way. I will never be calling the password hash from the DB to be used inside the user class (I will not use the user class for login verification).

Comment: Just don't ask the database server to hash it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no security concery passing your class plain text passwords. All that matters is to hash it before saving it permanently. (Remember: Saving it into session is permanent, since session data is saved to disk.)
The class and all its data is only present for the user who entered the plain-text password.

I would advice to do it inside the class: That enables you to add salting and other mechanisms on a central spot.

Keep in mind that you will do other checks for the password during registration progress: minimum length, allowed characters and so on. So hashing must happen after all these. As you want to be able to enable both COntroller and Model to add further checks, you need the hashing at the latest possible spot: Either on $user->save() or in the ORM class if used.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Depends if you use a HTTPS connection too. If so, you can hash your password into your code, because it won't be seen.
Hash a password with Javascript requires some code (because there isn't functions to hash in MD5 or SHA1, directly)

Like Zsolt said, hashing it into your class permits to use salt mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're right both solutions are good. Unless you're using some convention, then you should stick to it. Any way it is more important that you're consequent in the way you write your code. So it will be easier to read it, even for you after some time.